# NodeJs - near heap limit Allocation failed - JavaScript heap out of memory

Tags: node.js, ubuntu, amazon-ec2, cron

I have a node js application, running in `AWS EC2` as `m5xlarge` instance and `ubuntu 18.04` OS, which has a `main.js` file and in main file I am using `node-cron` to schedule multiple cron jobs,once the jobs are scheduled starting the application using another file `app.js`, in an intermittent way I am facing out of memory error and server stops the logs are shown as follows -

```
FATAL ERROR: Ineffective mark-compacts near heap limit Allocation failed - JavaScript heap out of memory
 1: node::Abort() [node /home/ubuntu/XXXXXX/main.js]
 2: 0x89371c [node /home/ubuntu/XXXXXX/main.js]
 3: v8::Utils::ReportOOMFailure(v8::internal::Isolate*, char const*, bool) [node /home/ubuntu/XXXXXX/main.js]
 4: v8::internal::V8::FatalProcessOutOfMemory(v8::internal::Isolate*, char const*, bool) [node /home/ubuntu/XXXXXX/main.js]
 5: 0xe617e2 [node /home/ubuntu/XXXXXX/main.js]
 6: v8::internal::Heap::PerformGarbageCollection(v8::internal::GarbageCollector, v8::GCCallbackFlags) [node /home/ubuntu/XXXXXX/main.js]
 7: v8::internal::Heap::CollectGarbage(v8::internal::AllocationSpace, v8::internal::GarbageCollectionReason, v8::GCCallbackFlags) [node /home/ubuntu/XXXXXX/main.js]
 8: v8::internal::Heap::AllocateRawWithRetry(int, v8::internal::AllocationSpace, v8::internal::AllocationAlignment) [node /home/ubuntu/XXXXXX/main.js]
 9: v8::internal::Factory::NewFillerObject(int, bool, v8::internal::AllocationSpace) [node /home/ubuntu/XXXXXX/main.js]
10: v8::internal::Runtime_AllocateInNewSpace(int, v8::internal::Object**, v8::internal::Isolate*) [node /home/ubuntu/XXXXXX/main.js]
11: 0x2a583f5041bd
```

The memory utilization and health check monitors are as follows -

[image: memory utilization and health check]

The spikes are due to cron job running on interval the highest ones are hourly cron job.

Now my assumption is it could be due to any of cron job failing with out of memory error in `main.js`, and hence the application in `app.js` also stops, or application itself failing in `app.js` the cron job scheduling looks like below -

```
const cluster = require('cluster');
const numCPUs = 1 //require('os').cpus().length;
var CronJob = require('cron').CronJob;
const spawn = require('child_process').spawn;
require('dotenv').config()

if (cluster.isMaster) {
   if (process.env.kEnvironment == "dev") {
        var sampleCron = new CronJob('00 */10 * * * *', function () {
            spawn(process.execPath, ['./sampleCron.js'], {
                stdio: 'inherit'
            })
        }, null, true, null);
    } else {
        var sampleCron = new CronJob('00 15 10 * * 0', function () {
            spawn(process.execPath, ['./sampleCron.js'], {
                stdio: 'inherit'
            })
        }, null, true, null);
    }
    // There are multiple cron like the above

    for (let i = 0; i < numCPUs; i++) {
        cluster.fork();
    }

    cluster.on('exit', (worker, code, signal) => {
        console.log(`worker ${worker.process.pid} died`);
    });

} else {
    require('./app.js');
}
```

Here is a htop preview about this -

[image: htop preview]

couple of questions here -
 - Why it shows main.js tree inside main.js, is that kind of nesting normal?
 - If it is same why the resource memory utilization differs for both?

I tried to increase the memory for each cron as below -

```
  var sampleCron = new CronJob('00 15 10 * * 0', function () {
            spawn(process.execPath, ['./sampleCron.js','--max-old-space-size=4096'], {
                stdio: 'inherit'
            })
        }, null, true, null);
```

But it still fails. My questions are as follows -

- How do I isolate the problem, is it really due to crons or due to application.
- How do I solve the problem?

Comment: In my gut feeling, it is mostly in the code , yo need to benchmark it , test it , profile it , as all cron does is perform a certain task at a certain time, period.

Comment: I agree, it might be due to code. However provided enough resources server should not crash, right? m5xlarge is 32 Gigs of memory with 4 core processor, in my opinion should be able to handle anything. Though the code needs to be optimized but as an immediate fix what could be the solution?

Comment: start dropping cron jobs one by one , and you will find the culprit OR even better do a top / htop and you will see which process is spiking

Comment: That is the problem as you see it all starts from main.js htop only blames main.js using 1.8 percent of memory. Droping cron job also is out of question since it is production app.

Comment: take code profile it locally to see if  the code is profiled properly and what are the hidden caveats

Answer (score 1):

Use commands like "Top" to find out how much memory the node process is using. I think the node script does not use all the available memory. you can also try allocating more memory using the NODE_OPTIONS. 
For e.g node SomeScript.js --max-old-space-size=8192

Comment: If you read the question carefully the mentioned steps are already in place.

Comment: Have you tried allocating memory to the main.js file?

Comment: Yes main is already allocated memory using `export NODE_OPTIONS=--max_old_space_size=4096`